# How to set up an android application to track crashes?

Tags: android, google-analytics, tracking

Currently I'm working on an android project. It is in closed beta now and I distributed beta invitations to some of my friends as beta testers. Not all of them are programmers so it is not easy for them to provide bug reports.
I'd like to add google analytics to the app in order to collect crash reports and maybe in another stage also usage statics.

For now crash reports are all I need. I read [the official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/), but I don't know how to apply what I read. As I understand, I can track specific activities such as an loading fragment or a clicked button. But that's not what I want. I would like to register a tracker for crashreports. How can I do that? I searched, but I didn't find a suiting tutorial.

Furthermore:
The Tutorial speaks of the `Application`. I have created a Fragment-Project with Android Studio and have no class derived from `Application`. What do I have to do to initialize my trackers?

The app is written for Android 4.1 (API level 16)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using Crashlytics.They provide the best error reporting services and yes they are free

Comment: Use crashlytics. Setup and usage is very simple

Comment: Is it impossible or so complicated to set up crash-reporting with google-analytics?

Comment: crashlytics is much more simpler to integrate than analytics and more widely used